# np.where in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

Right now I use the following user-defined function for np.where:

```
def np_where(condition, x, y){
    if (condition) return x else return y
}
```

I wonder if DolphinDB offers a built-in function for it?

Answer (score 0):

Function `iif` is what you were looking for.